# How to access music files stored on the iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift

My application is having trouble locating the files that are in the music folder on my iOS device.

If the files are held below as application data (in my playpen), no problem.  But when I go looking for the "Music" folder, using the following lines:

```
dest_dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .musicDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil,  create: false)

musicDir = dest_dir

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(musicDir) {
    print("found music directory")
}else {
    print("did not find music directory")
}
```

When the code executes the `canOpenURL`, I get a permissions complaint.

I also tried accessing the user directory (thinking I could then navigate into Music).

Any clues on how an application can access the files and playlists held under the music system folder on the iOS device?

Comment: When I run your code in my simulator it logs "found music directory" just fine.

Comment: @Aaron: that’s because the simulator currently doesn’t enforce sandboxing, which is what J. R. is running into here.

Comment: I guess I should thoroughly read the question before commenting. "playpen" threw me off.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the Music folder". To access the user's _music library_, use the Media Player framework.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as "the Music folder" in iOS. To access the user's *music library*, use the Media Player framework.

Example (assuming you have obtained the necessary authorization from the user):

```
let query = MPMediaQuery()
let result = query.items
```

Comment: Much more example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch16p678mediaQuery/ch29p946mediaQuery/ViewController.swift

Comment: Appreciate the hint.  Thanks

Comment: The app's Info.plist must contain an NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: @Matian2049 That is what I meant when I said "assuming you have obtained the necessary authorization from the user" in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! (Swift 4.2)

Inside a button method or @IBAction button

```
    let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songs().items
    let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems ?? [])
    let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
    player.setQueue(with: mediaCollection)
    player.play()


    let picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .anyAudio)
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
    picker.prompt = "Choose a song"
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn’t give you direct access to the Music folder, for security and privacy reasons; you need to use the APIs in the [MediaPlayer framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer). Assuming you’re trying to play content from the user’s library, take a look at [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller); you’ll need to provide it some [MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem) instances retrieved with an [MPMediaQuery](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery), then call methods from the [MPMediaPlayback protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaplayback) on the controller to make it play the content.

Comment: Appreciate the hint.  Thanks